# Automatically Extending a Background Image

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am trying to use an image for my background.  The content of the page has a height of 800px.  So on a tall screen you should be able to see a chunk of the background image after the content and on a shorter screen it may fit perfectly so that the content ends right at the bottom of the screen with little to no background image below.

I want the background image to automatically extend so no matter what size the screen is it will fill the entire screen.  I have tried a couple of things, like setting the height for `img.extfullbackground` to auto, but then the scroll area goes WAY to far down (like 3000px) and 100% only goes to the size of the content.

Does anyone know how I can make the background image automatically extend to the size of the screen?

Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
</head>

<body class="extfullbackground">
    <img class="extfullbackground" src=".\background.png" alt="background" />
    <div class="topbackground">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="topleft">
                    <img class="pf_logo" src=".\pf_logo.png" alt="PF Logo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="topmiddle">
                    <h1 class="title">PF is Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="topright" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div style="width:1220px; height:600px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:blue;">
        <div class="extcontentcontainer">
        <h2 class="subtitle">Please be patient while we update PF.</h2>
            <p class="pad10 line10">
```

Here's my CSS:  (note:  I used a CSS Reset script)

```
body {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.extcontentcontainer {
    width:820px;
    height:600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    background-color:red;
}

    img.extfullbackground {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%; /* alternative: right:0; */
        height:auto; /* alternative: bottom:0; */
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    background: url('background.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This worked for me on IE8. (it was an emulator on my iMac)

Else: why don't you set the image height to 100% and nothing for width. The image should keep it's ratio and extend to cover the entire height of the browser.

Comment: That works perfectly in IE.  In Firefox it works, BUT it only uses the very top of the image.  Is there a way so that in Firefox it uses the entire image..

Comment: try the moz prefix: `-moz-background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this (html):

```
<img src="bg.jpg" class="bg" alt="achtergrond">
```

css:

```
img.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-999;
    pointer-events: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

this will stretch the background to fill-screen when the screen is wider than 1024, and to stay 1024 px when less.

Comment: I'm concerned about the height though, not the width

Comment: When using this, the background will not be scrolling. The content will however.

Comment: Dammm that worked!!  The knowledge on this site never ceases to amaze me.  Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: Actually the only complaint I have is that it only uses the top part of the image.  Is there a way to have it so that it uses the entire image?

Comment: I could adjust the code so the image would be vertically centred, but when spread out over the screen (with right image ratio) you always lose a part of the image.